# canvas-ui error when uploading flipper.contract during substrate ink-workshop

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

When uploading the wasm binary, as a compiled smart contract on the 'ink-workshop' - the `canvas-ui` that I am running just errors.

Canvas-ui error:

```
Uncaught error. Something went wrong with the query and rendering of this component. 
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'args')
```

[image]

Step: 'Drag the flipper.contract file that contains the bundled wasm blob....'

The Github issues section associated is read-only, hence why I am posting here. Anyone know what might be the problem here?

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind as to repost this great question on https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ -- and @NukeManDan over there?
Very happy to assist on our shiny new Substrate (and friends) home for your questions! And as you have a great answer, bring it over too so we can upvote it there?

Comment: @NukeManDan certainly.

Answer (score 1):

Incase others are wondering what to do in this instance. I was able to deploy using the official [polkadot](https://docs.astar.network/build/smart-contracts/wasm/smart-contract/calling-your-contract) web interface.

Connect your local running node via settings and there you can deploy your flipper contract.

This is a good article on the [astar network docs](https://docs.astar.network/build/smart-contracts/wasm/smart-contract/calling-your-contract) on how to do it, using the basic `flipper contract` example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maintenance problem and they wanna fix it.

https://github.com/paritytech/canvas-ui/issues/119#issuecomment-1020114242